# How does ember data process a Form

Tags: ember-data

I'm trying to build an example for processing creation of objects through a form with Ember Data to insert into database.

So far my store shows the results in client side, but as far as processing the data to server, seems like my data is always undefined and creates blank records.

For now, my php API is not polished (that's why it allows the blank inserts) but since I'm running tests I'm just concerned with the data making it to the database.

How should I process a form with Ember Data? (And why is it using the 'createRecords' method instead of 'createRecord'?)

All help will be incredibly appreciated, I'm really trying to pull things out with Ember and hoping I will not have to drop and switch to another framework.

Here's my code where I'm attempting to create a Person via form and directly via code.
**Ember/JS:**

```js
App = Em.Application.create();

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    lastname: DS.attr('string'),

    didLoad: function() { 
        console.log(this.get('lastname') + " finished loading.");
    }
}).reopenClass({ 
    url: '../api/index.php?model=entity',
});



App.adapter = DS.Adapter.create({
    findAll: function (store, type) {
        var url = type.url+'&method=read';
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            store.loadMany(type, data);
        });
    },
    createRecord: function (store, type, model) {
        console.log(id);
        var url = type.url+'&method=create'

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: model.get('data'),
            //data: id,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST', 
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('didCreate');

            }
        })
    },
    createRecords: function (store, type, array) {
        $.ajax({
            url: type.url+'&method=create',
            data: array.mapProperty('data'),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                 store.didCreateRecords(type, array, data);
            }
        })
    },
    find: function(store, type, id) {
        console.log('find one');
        var url = type.url;
        url = url.fmt(id);
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            store.load(type, id, data);
        });
    }
});




App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 4,
  adapter: App.adapter
});

App.personController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    init: function(){
        this._super();
        this.set('content', App.store.findAll(App.Person));
    },
    loadCode: function() {
        content: [];
        var self = this; 
        var wycats = App.store.createRecord(App.Person,  {"id":"", "name":"12", "lastname":"Steve"});
        App.store.commit();
        console.log('from file');             

    },
    submitForm: function(event) {
        console.log('Called Sumbit');
        App.store.createRecord(App.Person, this.get("content"));
        App.store.commit();
    }

});

App.personView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'text'
});
```

**HTML:**

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<b>{{App.title}}</b><br>
{{view App.personView}}
Count: ({{App.personController.length }})
{{#each App.personController}}            
    <p>{{lastname}} {{name}}</p>
{{/each}}
</script> 
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="text">
    <h2>Create from Code</h2>
    <div class="send_form">
            <button {{action "loadCode" target="App.personController"}}>Create</button>
        <hr>
         <h2>Create from Form</h2>
    First name: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="lastname"}} <br/>
    Last name:  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="name"}} <br/>


    <button {{action "submitForm" target="App.personController"}}>Create</button>

    <h3>Current values: {{name}} {{lastname}}</h3>

    </div>
</script>​
```

**And the back-end API (PHP):**

```php
<?php

    require_once 'config.php';

    if (!$errors) {

    $method = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['method']);
    $model  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['model']);
    $format = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['format']);
    if($method === ''){
        $method = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['method']);
    }
    switch ($method) {
        case 'create' :

                $fieldlist=$vallist='';
                foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                    $fieldlist.=$key.',';
                    $vallist.='\''.urlencode($value).'\','; 
                }
                $fieldlist=substr($fieldlist, 0, -1);
                $vallist=substr($vallist, 0, -1);
                $return.= $vallist.' (val)
                ';
                $return.= $fieldlist .' (field)
                ';
                $query='INSERT INTO `test_'.$model.'` ('.$fieldlist.') VALUES ('.$vallist.')'; 
                $sql = mysql_query($query) or
                    die ('Error while getting data'.mysql_error());
                $return= $sql;



            break;

        case 'read' :
                $query = "SELECT * FROM  `test_{$model}`";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $return = array();
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                     $return[] = $row;
                }
                $return= json_encode($return);
            break;

        case 'reads' :
                $query = "SELECT * FROM  `test_{$model}`";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $return='{ "'.$model.'" : ';
                $resultados = array();
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                     $resultados[] = $row;
                }
                $return.= json_encode($resultados);
                $return.=' }';

            break;


    }

    mysql_close();

    switch ($format) {
        default :
                echo $return;
            break;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Hard to know - that's a lot of code. You should insert the `debugger` statement after `App.store.createRecord(App.Person, this.get("content"));`, and then debug into your code in the JS console.

Comment: How should I use the fields in my form to process them through createRecord() so I can create the record? Right now it's just creating a record with undefined properties. I try to debug but I'm not sure how to send this values to the method to populate the array, and then the database.

Comment: `App.store.createRecord(App.Person, {"id":"", "name":"12", "lastname":"Steve"})` looks right. Instead of the object literal you can also pass an Ember object.